# Which structure for fast split / removeTail and insert operation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for sorted structure which allows fast split / removeTail and insert(key) operations. These are only 3 operations I need. I know that there is relation like 9:1 for `removeTail(k)` to `insert(k)` queries. Additionally, most of the `removeTail(k)` will remove 0 elements, occasionally 10-50.

I am considering Red-Black / AVL Tree, Treap, SkipList and simple sorted array.

AVL Tree - simpler split operations than RBT, but maybe it makes no sense to split whole tree, when occasionally I have to remove just 10-50 elements?

Treap - easy splits but maybe no worth it as above?

SkipList - too high insert overhead anyway

Sorted Array - on insert binary search for index and then shift all elements to right, `removeTail(k)` pretty fast, just go from end until `k >= array[i]`

Splay Tree - ?

I'm going to benchmark these all, but maybe you can point out some additional structures which are worthwhile to conclude in benchmarks?

Structure will have from 10 to 50 000 elements - perhaps I will implement it this way, that it transforms from some simple array to tree when elements exceeds some threshold. Basically it depends, some clients have only few elements, others a lot of them up to about 50 000

Trim ratio (when removeTail(k) returns something) to "do nothing" (k greater than max) is like 1:500

Comment: 1) How many items in the data structure (dozens/1000,millions)?

2) > most of the removeTail(k) will remove 0 elements
so, this is just comparison K with size of the data structure. Mostly, do nothing. What is the ratio when you need to trim?

Comment: SkipList inserts are comparable to trees... Similar for splits, if you don't rebuild the skips, but removing the "tail" would be not fast. What do you consider the "tail" of a tree?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Tail means greaterThan(k)

Comment: Binary heap? Priority queue? If sorted in descending order, you pop top K elements out to remove in O(K) time, then all inserts are log(N).

Comment: Yeah, heap sounds good if there won't be many splits, thanks

Comment: @OneCricketeer Removing the top k elements from a binary heap is O(k log n), not O(k).

Comment: With skip lists you randomly assign a height to your node and insert it in the skip list (with a non-uniform distribution). The overhead shouldn't be any worse than inserting into a tree except you may even have better cache locality then in a tree giving you good performance.

Skip lists are especially good for deletes because they don't involve all the rearranging that balanced trees require.